# Conditional Sum Based on Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have reviewed the various 'Conditional Sum' questions in the forum and none quite match what I'm trying to do:

In the database, there is `Date`, `Store#`, `Item#`, and `%Total Sales`.  In some cases, the same item# for the same date may be given more than one value for `%Total Sales`. (For some reason this is a valid business scenario that happens rarely, but it happens.)

In that situation only, the requirement is to sum the two values together into one line. So if Item# 123 has a line with a value of .05%, and another line with a value of .08%, I need to sum those two values into one line for Item #123 that has a `%Total` of .13%. ONLY when an item has more than one percentage assigned, those percentages should be summed.  Otherwise, if an item# has only one percentage value assigned, we just want to see that value.

I cannot figure out how to do this.  Basically, I would like to implement logic that would work like this:

```
SELECT Date, Store#, Item#, 
CASE WHEN Count(%Total Sales) >1 THEN Sum(%Total Sales) 
ELSE %Total Sales
END

FROM (some tables and joins)
GROUP BY Date, Store#, Item#
```

However, I'm not sure how to craft it so that I don't get a syntax error (this query produces errors).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why does it need to be conditional? If you group by all the fields then you should only be summing values that have multiple lines anyway

Comment: What is the datatype of totalSales field?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you group by `Date, Store#, Item#` the only values that return multiple lines are those with multiple values for Total Sales of the same item on the same date.

Therefore grouping the items should be sufficient.

```
SELECT Date, Store#, Item#, Sum(%Total Sales) 
FROM (some tables and joins)
GROUP BY Date, Store#, Item#
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an update instead of entering a new value in the table.
Rather than manipulating of the data after insertions.

I believe this is a better idea that you can check for the existing date and update the percentage at that moment itself.

Is it not possible?